# Bind Strings from an .resw file with ReswFileCodeGenerator in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, localization, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I tried to localize my Windows Universal App with the Multilingual app toolkit.
Because you can't bind strings directly from a .resw file in XAML, I used the ReswFileCodeGenerator tool. It works great in code behind, but in XAML I can't get this right.

In Windows Phone 8.0 I could use:

```
Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.StringName, Source={StaticResource Strings}}"
```

Is there a similar way in Windows (Phone) 8.1 with the ReswFileGenerator tool?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would still suggest you do it as Depechie already suggested: use `x:Uid` attribute.

If you need to get the localized string from code, just replace `.` in resource name with `/`. So, in XAML you'll write:

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="appString" />
```

In code you'll use:

```
var resourceLoader = new ResourceLoader();
var localizedText = resourceLoader.GetString("appString/Text");
```

Answer (score 3):

When doing resource translations in wp8.1 with .resw files, you need to use the x:Uid attribute on your xaml control!

Like `<TextBlock x:Uid="FieldKey" />`

[Details are mentioned here...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965326.aspx)

Comment: I've done it before with x:Uid, but it was to inconvenient, because for XAML I always need to write "appString.Text" in my .resw file. Which can't be used in Code behind (there I only need "appString").

Comment: @Cristian126 `appString.Text` can be used in code behind as well. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: The problem of Microsoft's approach is to force the resource file to adapt to xaml use. Most language resources are shared between projects for WP, iOS and Android. The current approach to force a new naming convention of the keys on the developers like "FieldKey.Text" is not helpful for this reuse purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I've coded something to help me with this. It may not be perfect, but works great for me. Here's a [link to the helper](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A6C2D3754FAFFD50!31993&authkey=!ADc5Zqo1MNTKg24&ithint=file%2czip). You build it and put the .exe file in some easy-to-reach folder.

In the project with the resources, you set the pre-build action to something like this (you only need to change the *"path\to\ResourcesHelper.exe"* part):

```
call "path\to\ResourcesHelper.exe" "$(TargetName)" "$(ProjectDir)\" "$(RootNameSpace)" "universal"
```

Also, the main resources must be in *Resources/en-US* folder of your project (you can change it in the code, though).

This way, when you build the project, it will generate a file called *LocalizedStrings.cs* which is something like the file generated for .resx files. It contains some additional properties called LC (for lower case), UC (for upper case) and UCF (for upper case first) which return the strings in that casing. I hope you'll find it useful. :)

Note: The tool wasn't meant for other people, so I really just coded what I needed, so it may not work flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've added the pre-build action and the .resw file to the Resources/en-US folder. But where I now can find the LocalizedStrings.cs file? Should I  
modify the Custom Build Tool from the .resw file?

Comment: @Cristian126 After you've built the project with the pre-build action, the file will be created in the project's main folder (that's above the Resources folder). You'll have to include it manually to the project though. Use the "show all files" button and then include the file. It's in the folder, just not in the project itself.